# Project all fields in aggregation in elasticserach

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know how I can project all the fields in my aggs query in elasticsearch. Suppose that I have this dataset:

```
{
sent_id: 1
doc_id: 5
text: "test1"
year: "2015"
}
{
sent_id: 2
doc_id: 5
text: "test2"
year: "2015"
}
```

I want to do a group by based on my doc_id for all sentences that has certain criteria. I want the results like this:

```
doc_id:5
{
    {sent_id:1, year:2015, text: "test1"},
    {sent_id:2, year:2015, text: "test2"}, 
    etc
},
doc_id: xx
{ 
    {sent_id:xx, year:2015, text: "xx"}
}
```

following gives me more or less what I want except it does not project all other fields.

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["text"],
      "query" : "affordable energy"}}
  ,"size": 0
  ,"aggs":{
    "doc_id":{
            "terms": {
        "field": "doc_id"
        ,"size": 0
      },
       "aggs": {
            "sents_info": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "sent_id",
                    "size": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  "aggs": {
    "doc_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "doc_id",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sents_info": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sent_id",
            "size": 0
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top10": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```